# Stream of English and Tamil alphabets

Tags: algorithm

There is an infinite bit stream that holds combination of Tamil and English characters along with a pointer pointing into the middle of the bit stream. A Tamil character is 2 octets with a 1 as the MSB. An English character is 1 octet with a 0 as the MSB. How do I find which character is just before the pointer?

Comment: The problem description isn't clear enough to answer. What does it mean to have a pointer pointing into the middle of a bit stream? Can it point to an arbitrary bit? Does "A Tamil character is 2 octets with a 1 as the MSB" mean that each octet has a 1 as the most significant bit? Can you edit the question to add the missing details?

Comment: It's also unclear where you're stuck -- can you state what you've done to solve the problem, and exactly what you're stuck on?

Comment: following are the cases (just giving MSB)
1) 01 - the octet before my pointer will be stating of Tamil character
2) 00 - English character
3) 11 - Tamil Character
4) 10 - the octer earlier could be English or Tamil. to find this i have to traverse full stream and i am stuck here.
sub case for 4
       a) 010 - earlier octet is Tamil.
       b) 110 - could be English or Tamil, to find this i should traverse full stream